# Парсинг sqlite в xml

Tags: база-данных, objective-c, xml, sqlite, парсер

Есть приложение, которое сохраняет созданные в приложении текстовые элементы в *sqlite* файл, каждый из этих элементов возможно отправить через *email* в виде *pdf* файла.
Необходимо сделать парсинг *sqlite* файла и отдельно вытянуть из него каждый созданный элемент (и элемент, который будет еще создан) в *xml* файл. К примеру, чтобы получалась картинка, не *plans.sqlite*, а *plans.sqlite*, *element1.xml*, *element2.xml*..."

P.S.: В документации нашел класс `NSXMLParser`, который, как я понял, отвечает за это действие, но не нашел примеров или объяснений поэтапных действий.

Answer (score 1):

NSXMLParser вам не поможет - это обычный SAX-парсер и писать в xml не умеет. Честно говоря, не совсем понял что вы хотите - sqlite это же база данных и её не надо парсить, к ней можно смело обращаться пользуясь его апи (в настольном маке не знаю, в iOS SDK оно входит как libsqlite3.dlyb) или какой нибудь надстройкой типа CoreData, если бы мне понадобилось перегонять все в xml я бы формировал его напрямую из строк.

Comment: Понял про парсинг.
Хорошо, а как тогда возможно реализовать формирование из строк?
эллемент у меня состоит из "имя", "учитель", "класс", ниже по древовидной системе уже расположены координаты на графики и т.д.
Вот мне и необходимо вывести отдельно все елементы "имя", в которые уже будут входить все координаты, "учитель", "класс" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте `.dump` данных, потом данные можно превратить в XML - это уже вопрос техники, например можно использовать CDATA

Answer (score 0):

Начать следует с вопроса - что такое [РСУБД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) вообще, и [SQLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite) в частности. Потом нужно обратиться к [документации](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) SQLite. После этого вам станет ясен порядок действий, а именно:

1. получить данные из базы
2. если нужно, то соответствующим образом их обработать
3. сформировать xml

Этот алгоритм совсем уж общий, но из вашего вопроса следует, что проблема у вас именно в его непонимании.

Comment: На самом деле стоит вопрос немного по другому. А именно:
В iPhone App данный, создаваемые в приложении сохраняются в отдельные pdf файлы, которые можно отослать по email и т.д. Эти Pdf файлы сохраняются в общую базу sqlite3 и работают только в однм приложении.
Задача заказчика стоит в том, что бы каждый pdf файл сохранялся отдельно в xml и pdf файлах и они по прежнему сохранялись в базу данных sqlite3, но при интеграции с iTunes можно было бы взять один из этих файлов и использовать в другом таком же app'e, но на другом девайса.
Вот и задаюсь вопросом, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: В любом случае с sqlite надо работать через его api, парсить его не нужно. Его база - некое хранилище чего угодно с удобным доступом к отдельным элементам, выборку которых можно делать с помощбю sql запросов ([примеры запросов](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)) по различным условиям. В документации все это есть.

Примеры кода: [один](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/02/sqlite-tutorial-saving-images-in.html), [два](http://www.iosdevelopment.be/sqlite-tutorial/)